# Контекст возбуждения - (не) только сексуальный?

Tags: выражения, одним-словом

Если человек, получив интересную информацию, не разволновался, а эмоционально вовлекся и заинтересовался, стал активно размышлять на эту тему - какими словами это лучше описать?

"Возбуждающая тема", "разговор оказал возбуждающее действие", "услышав идею, он пришел в сильное возбуждение / чрезвычайно возбудился" - можно ли так сказать, не вызывая нежелательные в данном случае сексуальные коннотации, или есть более подходящие слова?

Совсем по-другому звучат в то же время сочетания с существительными: "возбудить интерес, негодование".

Comment: Так вопрос в том, используется ли слово "возбуждающий" без сексуальной коннотации, или в том, чем заменить это слово? Или в том, как одним-двумя словами сказать "эмоционально вовлекся и заинтересовался"? Это три разных вопроса.

Answer (score 6):

Волнующая тема. Разговор сильно взволновал его.

Он воодушевился. - но это только позитивное переживание.

Он разволновался. Он разнервничался. - но это только негативное переживание.

Comment: воодушевление вроде бы то что искал! :) спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Я бы еще сказал "будоражащая идея", "эта идея его взбудоражила". Похоже на английское "exciting/excited", с немного более сильным значением. 
Но, вообще, я бы не сказал, что вне контекста слово "возбуждать" имеет однозначные сексуальные коннотации. Кофе, например, тоже возбуждающий эффект имеет (invigorating).

Answer (score 3):

**Захватывающий** :

Захватывающий и непредсказуемый сюжет фильма
"*Заводной апельсин*" не даст расслабиться до самого конца.

захватывающая идея.

"Именно такая идея и захватила [Раскольникова](https://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?mode=sochi&sochid=2089). Человек стал рабом своей теории."

Answer (score 3):

Я бы рекомендовал слово "загореться":

"он загорелся этой идеей"